# Using Wildcard with WMIC Version Query

Tags: powershell, wmi-query, wmic

I am an InfoSec admin with an okay amount of PowerShell experience.  I'll keep it short and sweet:

```
([WMI] "\\$comp\root\CIMV2:CIM_DataFile.Name='$path'").Version)
```

I use this for calling file versions instead of using get-item VersionInfo.ProductVersion, since this does not always return an accurate value.  It works well.  However, when $path is equal to something like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\Flash*.ocx
```

The query doesn't work because the file is not found.  I imagine this is due to the single quotes around the variable ignoring the wildcard.

I will admit that I did find a work around to my problem here (the answer posted by JPBlanc):

[Powershell get-item VersionInfo.ProductVersion incorrect / different than WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090875/powershell-get-item-versioninfo-productversion-incorrect-different-than-wmi)

However, I want to know if it is possible for me to use a wildcard with my existing script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a wildcard directly, but you can query the filesystem with that wildcard and then loop through the results. In both cases here, I'm assuming that you're doing this remotely.

```
$FlashFiles = invoke-command -computername $comp {Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\Flash*.ocx;};
foreach ($File in $FlashFiles) {
    write-output "$($File.Fullname): $(([WMI] "\\$comp\root\CIMV2:CIM_DataFile.Name='$($File.FullName)'").Version)"
}
```

Or do it with a single pipeline:

```
invoke-command -computername $comp {Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\Flash*.ocx||foreach-object {write-output "$($_.Fullname): $(([WMI] "\\$comp\root\CIMV2:CIM_DataFile.Name='$($_.FullName)'").Version)"};
```

You can make the latter even faster by running the WMI query local to the remote computer (you could do it with the first too, but it's not as pretty)

```
invoke-command -computername $comp {Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\Flash*.ocx|foreach-object {write-output "$($_.Fullname): $(([WMI] "\\.\root\CIMV2:CIM_DataFile.Name='$($_.FullName)'").Version)"}};
```

Comment: Thank you, Alroc.  This is what I was looking for.  I'd vote you up, but my reputation isn't high enough!

Answer (score 0):

The `Name` property of a `CIM_DataFile` can't contain wildcards.  I don't believe any of them can.

However, you can specify the `Drive`, `Path`, and `Extension` to get a list:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $comp -Class CIM_DataFile -Filter "Drive='C:' AND Path='\\Windows\\System32\\Macromed\\Flash\\' AND Extension='ocx'"
```

The syntax of `Path` is a bit flaky.  You need the trailing backslashes, for example.

You can also pipe to `Where-Object` for further filtering:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $comp -Class CIM_DataFile -Filter "Drive='C:' AND Path='\\Windows\\System32\\Macromed\\Flash\\' AND Extension='ocx'" |`
Where-Object { $_.FileName -like 'Flash*' } |`
ForEach-Object { $_.Name; $_.Version }
```